# Windows: Terminate a process: ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: windows, terminate, createprocess

I am trying to call TerminateProcess on my child process (only to be as a safety mechanism used when the child gets into a deadlock or something drastic) but I am getting ERROR_INVALID_HANDLER.

I've tried playing with the Process settings but it hasn't helped. If I call TerminateProcess() right after CreateProcess(), the call does work.

```
BOOL ret;
HANDLE hProcess;

hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE,
                        FALSE,
                        pid);

if (hProcess = NULL) {
    debug("Error: OpenProcess failed: %d", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}

ret = TerminateProcess(hProcess, 1);
CloseHandle(hProcess);

if (!ret) {
    debug("Error: TerminateProcess failed: %d", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
else return 0;
```

I am getting the error 6, INVALID_HANDLE_EXCEPTION. I double checked and the pid is correct (it matches what's in the Task Manager). The only possible error may be how I get the handle with OpenProcess().I tried to use PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS but that didn't work as well.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong please?

EDIT: Shoot such a stupid error! I was assigning NULL to hProcess ('=' rather than '==')

Sorry for the post!

Comment: Your if() statement assigns NULL to hProcess.  Use the == operator instead.  And call GetLastError() *immediately* after failure, not after CloseHandle().

Comment: "I am getting ERROR_INVALID_HANDLER". No, you are getting "I am getting ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE".

Comment: Thank you, I noticed my mistake, it's hard to see sometime (not looking just at those lines). I appreciate the help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (hProcess = NULL)
```

this is an assignment not a condition, change the "=" to "=="